# "Usually it's them waiting for me."

Tags: sentence-structure, cleft-constructions

The sentence is said to appear in a textbook.
I feel this is a cleft sentence to emphasize 'them,' but then it's omitting 'who are' before the 'waiting,' but is this way of expression common?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  While inserting a "who are" would still be proper, the form as it is is more common.  The emphasis can be a slightly split if the sentence is referring to the opposite of the norm, which I can't tell from the current context.

An opposite situation:
"Usually it's *me* flirting with the *ladies*, but since I got this sports car it's backwards."

A common situation:
"As a priest, when people come to confession usually it's *them* doing all the talking to me."